# Extract month from user input

Tags: watson-conversation

I'm new to watson conversation API.I'm building simple chatbot. i want to extract month from user input for a bill query .
for example ,
If user ask for current month bill , bot should extract current month as February and respond "Please find your February month bill below ".
Please help.
Thanks,
Dillip

Answer (score 4):

To achieve this first you need to enable system entities `@sys-date`.

Then check to ensure that `@sys-date` has been hit, and you can use the following code:

```
<? @sys-date.reformatDateTime('MMMM') ?>
```

Example:

[image]

This will generate the following output:

[image]

More details on system entities here: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/system-entities.html